# replace text with a longer text in a text file on python

Tags: python

I have an text file having the content as follows

```
1 0.374023 0.854818 0.138672 0.230469
0 0.939941 0.597005 0.118164 0.782552
1 0.826118 0.582643 0.347764 0.803151
1 0.503418 0.822266 0.100586 0.240885
```

I want to replace "1", at the beginning, with "80"
like following:

```
80 0.374023 0.854818 0.138672 0.230469
0 0.939941 0.597005 0.118164 0.782552
80 0.826118 0.582643 0.347764 0.803151
80 0.503418 0.822266 0.100586 0.240885
```

keeping the rest of the content same.

Comment: The bytes in a file are sequential. You can't replace 1 byte with two in the file. You'll have to read the full content from the file. Then do the changes and write back the full content to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short version using regex and list comprehension:

```
import re

with open('source.txt', 'r') as infile:
    reformatted = [re.sub(r'^1', '80', line) for line in infile.readlines()]

with open('source.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    [outfile.write(line) for line in reformatted]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing in two step file opening:

```
with open("a_file.txt","r") as f:
    lines = a.readlines()

lines = ["80"+line[1:] if line[0:2]=="1 " else line for line  in lines]
#OR
lines =["80"+line[1:] if line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] == "1" else line for line  in lines] 

with open("a_file.txt","w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: This is problematic, if numbers starting with 1 are possible. For example `10 0.37......`

Comment: Use `line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] == "1"` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to use python, then this can be done easily with `sed` using the following:

```
sed -i 's/^1/80/g' input_file.txt
```

The `s/<regex>/<replacement>/g` means replace all occurrences of `<regex>` with `<replacement>`. The `^1` is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that means "match any '1' at the beginning of the line".

Alternatively, the following python code will do the same thing:

```
file = open("input_file.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
outFile = open("input_file.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    split = line.strip().split(" ")
    split[0] = 80 if (split[0] == "1") else split[0]
    print(*split, file=outFile)
```

Where you just loop through each line, and replace "1" at the beginning of the line with 80.

Answer (score 0):

The input file contains lines made up of [white]space delimited tokens. If the first token equals '1' change it to '80'.

This can be achieved as follows:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r+') as foo:
    lines = foo.readlines()
    foo.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        if (tokens := line.split())[0] == '1':
            tokens[0] = '80'
        print(*tokens, file=foo)
    foo.truncate()
```

**Note:**

Use of truncate isn't really necessary in this case because the file size will not increase but is a failsafe pattern for this kind of read/rewrite process